# Send custom Referer when accessing a *specific* site via HTTPS (and not HTTP)

Tags: firefox, privacy, http

(Note that I asked a (broader) [question on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/584918/151741) some time ago.)

I’m using the Firefox add-on [RefControl](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/refcontrol/) to control which [`Referer`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) gets sent to pages I visit.

It works great, but I’m missing one feature: When setting a custom `Referer` for a specific site, you can’t define to send it only when accessing the site via HTTPS (background: [use case](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/33942/12139)). It gets sent no matter if I access the site via HTTP or HTTPS.

Is there a Firefox add-on that allows this?

(A solution doesn’t have to offer all features of RefControl, as long as I could use it in combination with RefControl.)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell there was no equivalent options. However the great thing about Mozilla addons is that they are an easy to edit thing. [RefControl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/refcontrol/) is also nicely open-source (MPL).

This means that I did what I've been meaning to do for a while... learn Firefox addon creation and editing. So without further ado/blowing my horn etc.

I've forked RefControl and edited it to care about what scheme/protocol is being used. It is the first Firefox package I've editing so use with care but I don't think there are any bugs - that being said please do report any you find. You can download/install [my fork](http://briarmoon.ca/design/RefControl.xpi) from my website.

Comment: Very nice! Do you intend to submit it to [Mozilla Add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/)?

Comment: @unor I see there has bee no activity for 3 years on the addon; I've sent an email to the original developer to look into it. I given the license I could just go ahead but I prefer to talk first before going that route.

Comment: Sure, fair enough. (FWIW, I emailed the creator last and this year, but never got a reply.)

Comment: @Unor hmm in that case I'll probably wait less time before considering him uncontactable if I hear nothing

Comment: @Unor I had some thoughts I wanted to discuss with you since you are a user of RefControl original and been trying out my fork. However I can't see any contact info on your page... would you be interested in a chat about RefControl? (kinda out of scope for the comments section) - I can be emailed or chat with most chat protocols if there is any way you prefer.